# Convert JSONArray into a String Array

Tags: android, json, arrays

Probably a stupid question. I'm getting a JSONArray in the form of

```
[{'route':'route1'}, {'route':'route2'}, {'route':'route3'}]
```

I want to get it into a String array of

```
["route1", "route2", "route3"]
```

How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that comes to my mind would be to iterate through and just grab the values

```
String[] stringArray = new String[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    stringArray[i]= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("route");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @nyx. your answer helped me lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);

        if (jsonArray != null) {

            String[] strArray = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                strArray[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("route");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed by this [TUTORIAL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```

Or use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Collection<Integer> ints = Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);

//(Serialization)
String json = gson.toJson(ints); ==> json is [1,2,3,4,5]

//(Deserialization)
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
//ints2 is same as ints
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solutions,

Just replace { and } by following code

```
String jsonString = jsonArray.toString();
jsonString.replace("},{", " ,");
String[]array = jsonString.split(" ");
```

Or

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```

this will convert to Arraylist and then if you want it to string then convert it to StringArray. for more reference use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871309/convert-jsonarray-to-string-array)

Answer (score 0):

as straight forward as it can be

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for( int ix = 0; ix < yourArray.length(); ix++ ){
  list.add( yourArray.getJSONObject( ix ).getString( "route" ) );
}
return list.toArray( new String[] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way here i gave with demo code
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("route","route1");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject2.put("route","route2");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);
            JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject3.put("route","route3");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject3);

            String[] array = jsonArrayToArray(jsonArray);

            for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                Log.i((i+1)+" Route : ",array[i]);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public String jsonToStrings(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        String data ="";
        Iterator keys = object.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            data+=fromJson(object.get(key)).toString()+",";
        }
        return data;
    }


    private Object fromJson(Object json) throws JSONException {
        if (json == JSONObject.NULL) {
            return null;
        } else if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            return jsonToStrings((JSONObject) json);
        } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
            return jsonArrayToArray((JSONArray) json);
        } else {
            return json;
        }
    }

    private String[] jsonArrayToArray(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        int size = array.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(fromJson(array.get(i)));
        }
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            String[] row = ((String)((String)list.get(i)).subSequence(0,((String)list.get(i)).length()-1)).split(",");
            for (int j=0;j<row.length;j++){
                arrayList.add(row[j]);
            }
        }
        String[] strings = new String[arrayList.size()];
        for (int k=0;k<strings.length;k++){
            strings[k]=arrayList.get(k);
        }

        return strings;
    }

}
```