# How to convert JSON String to Arraylist<JSONObj>

Tags: android, android-intent

I have String like

```
[
   {
     "Title":"name",
     "Value":"Sam"
   }, 

   {
     "Title":"mobile",
     "Value":"(606) 87-0238"
   }
]
```

want to convert it into `List<JSONobj>` list of JSONObject.

Comment: can we see what you have tried so far? so that we can append our ideas to your ideas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use JsonParser to parse this String. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Please mind all above comments and visit [Convert JSONArray to String Array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15871355/2032561)

Comment: please elaborate how to use Jsonparser fro this String

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayLis<JSONObject> list=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

JSONArray arr= new JSONArray("json string");

for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){

JSONObject obj=arr.getJSONObject(i);

list.add(obj);

}
```

You have to do something like this.

Comment: This should be Correct in my case.