# Convert JsonArrayString to List<String> or String[]

Tags: java, json

How to convert a `JsonArrayString` to `List<String>` or `String[]`? I tried to use Gson to covert it, but I failed. Maybe I overlooked some existing methods which can do this? Any other better way to make it or can someone give me some tips?

```
[
    {
        "test": "test"
    },
    {
        "test": "test"
    },
    {
        "test": "test",
        "test2": "test2",
        "test3": [
            {
                "test": "test"
            },
            {
                "test": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871309/convert-jsonarray-to-string-array after validating your json data in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont know if the value is a JSONObject or a JSONArray. In thise case you may want to use a Map and a Object as Value like this (not tested).

```
class Model { 
  private Map<String, Object> test;
}
```

Take care that you have to validate if the Value is a JSONArray or a JSONObject using (for example):

```
if (this.getTest().getValue() instanceof JSONObject.class) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Finally find the way to resovel:

```
    // Converting JSON String array to Java String array
    String jsonStringArray = "[{\"test\":\"test1\"},{\"test\":\"test2\"},{\"test\":\"test3\",\"test2\":[{\"test\":\"test1\"},{\"test\":\"test2\"}]}]";

    // creating Gson instance to convert JSON array to Java array
    Gson converter = new Gson();

    Type type = new TypeToken<List>() {
    }.getType();
    List list = converter.fromJson(jsonStringArray, type);

    // convert List to Array in Java

    System.out.println("Java List created from JSON String Array - example");
    System.out.println("JSON String Array : " + jsonStringArray);
    System.out.println("Java List : " + list);

    // let's now convert Java array to JSON array -
    String toJson = converter.toJson(list);
    System.out.println("Json array created from Java List : " + toJson);
```

output:

```
Java List created from JSON String Array - example
JSON String Array : [{"test":"test1"},{"test":"test2"},    
{"test":"test3","test2":[{"test":"test1"},{"test":"test2"}]}]
Java List : [{test=test1}, {test=test2}, {test=test3, test2=[{test=test1},   {test=test2}]}]
Json array created from Java List : [{"test":"test1"},{"test":"test2"},{"test":"test3","test2":[{"test":"test1"},{"test":"test2"}]}]
```

Comment: I used to mistakely set the Type, I should be List not List<String>