# How to parse this jsonarray to string or array java

Tags: java, parsing

I have this string from json, but i don`t know how to get values in quotes

```
[  
   "black-chest-close.png",
   "diamond-chest-close.png",
   "gold-chest-close.png",
   "logo.png",
   "logo1.png",
   "ruby-chest-close.png",
   "sapphire-chest-close.png"
]
```

Comment: Type "Java JSON parsing" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: [Convert JSONArray to String Array
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871309/convert-jsonarray-to-string-array)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the square brackets with curly ones and just insantiate an String array - no JSON required

```
String arr[] =  {"black-chest-close.png","diamond-chest-close.png","gold-chest-close.png",
                 "logo.png","logo1.png","ruby-chest-close.png","sapphire-chest-close.png"};
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) also you can parse above json like

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```