# Using simple json, transform a json object containing a json array into an array of strings (in java)

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

**As this question has been closed before actual answer for this specific problem has been found, it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612759/6213883).**

In java, I am using the [simplejson library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple111jar.htm) to handle json.

My json have this structure (truncated):

```
{

    "assembling-tags": {
        "list": [
            "G_StaticCushion_R",
            "G_CommutationPosition_R",
            "G_PlastificationPlasticisingDuration_R",
            "G_PlastificationScrewPositionAfter_R",
            "G_CommutationPressure_R",
            "G_DynamicCommutationDuration_R",
            "G_DynamicLockingToolDuration_R",
            "G_CycleTime_R",
            "CYCLE_TIME",
            "G_ClosureSecurityClosingToolDuration_R"
        ]
    },
```

I read the json data with the following code:

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(
                "/home/hduser/eclipse-workspace/db-simulatiob/src/generator-config.json")) {

            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
```

And I am trying to convert the list json array into a string array, with the following:

```
String[] aTag = (String[]) ((JSONObject) obj.get("assembling-tags")).get("list");
```

But this throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

How can I convert the json array into a string array (`String[]`) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSONArray to String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871309/convert-jsonarray-to-string-array)

Comment: The exception is trying to tell you something, did you read it?

Comment: @Smile No, as I want a String[] and not an ArrayList<String>. (WIll edit question for this detail). Also I am working with jsonsimple, so I have a JSON Object (see code), not a string.

Comment: @f1sh Yes. And I do not know how to solve this, thus the question.

Comment: Did you read **all** the answers on that question. The second answer shows how to create a string array.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, and it uses `org.json.*;`, I am using `org.json.simple.*;`. These are not the same libraries.

Comment: As far as I know, the principle is the same. In any case, you cannot cast a `JSONObject` to a `String[]` like you're doing.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Posted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612759/6213883) as it is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, Hopefully it will solved your problem:

```
String jstr = "{\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "    \"assembling-tags\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"list\": [\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_StaticCushion_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_CommutationPosition_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_PlastificationPlasticisingDuration_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_PlastificationScrewPositionAfter_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_CommutationPressure_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_DynamicCommutationDuration_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_DynamicLockingToolDuration_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_CycleTime_R\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"CYCLE_TIME\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"G_ClosureSecurityClosingToolDuration_R\"\r\n" + 
                "        ]\r\n" + 
                "    }}";

        JSONObject obj  = new JSONObject(jstr);
        JSONArray jarr = obj .getJSONObject("assembling-tags").getJSONArray("list");
        String[] aTag =new String[jarr.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<aTag.length; i++) {
            aTag[i]=jarr.optString(i);
        } // aTag is ready to use 

        // Here I just print the output
        for(int i=0; i<aTag.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("jsonArray to String array:"+aTag[i]); 
        }
```

Also import below:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Comment: I am working with jsonsimple. A `JSONObject` does not have the method `getJSONObject` :S