# i want to show days of week from sunday to monday from the string "[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]" in android

Tags: android

Here is my string getting from json response:

```
daysOfDelivery = getIntent().getStringExtra("DaysOfDelivery");
```

in `daysOfDelivery` i have a String `"[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]"`

using this string i want to show days of week from sunday to monday

Comment: So what's the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
 List<String> weekDayslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    String availabilityDays = "";
    String frequency;

    frequency = getIntent().getStringExtra("Frequency");
    if (frequency != null) {
        availabilityDays = getIntent().getStringExtra("DaysOfDelivery");
    }

    if (!availabilityDays.isEmpty()) {
        availabilityDays = availabilityDays.replaceAll("[\(\)\[\]\\{\\}]", "");
        for (String field : availabilityDays.split(",")
        )
            weekDayslist.add(field);
    }
```

Comment: not working for me?, is there any solution

Comment: how do u want to have the days? in a list?

Comment: I have updated the answer, this should help

Comment: i have a frequecy, if it is daily then i get a string above daysOfDelivery string,and i want to convert that string to arraylist and show the days using for loop in a horizontal listview

Comment: Updated answer is doing exactly that, you can apply for loop on weekDayslist

Comment: ok i will do, thanks @Usman Zafer

Comment: frequency = getIntent().getStringExtra("Frequency");
        if (frequency != null){
            availabilityDays = getIntent().getStringExtra("DaysOfDelivery");
            if (availabilityDays != null){
                String daysOfDelivery =availabilityDays;
                daysOfDelivery = daysOfDelivery.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]","");
                List<String> weekDayslist = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String field : daysOfDelivery.split(","))
                    weekDayslist.add(field);
            }      
        }

Comment: not working plese solve this

Comment: use the updated answer

Comment: can we Convert the JSON array string to a List object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871355/7303915

Comment: take a look here