# How to convert JSONArray to Java String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to extract authors from this JSON, I successfully get the `JSONArray` but I don't know how to convert it into `String[]`, I have to pass this `String[]` to a method. Please try to keep the solution simple as I am just a beginner.

JSON :

```
{
  "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Android",
    "authors": [
      "P.K. Dixit"
    ]
  }
}
```

Code:

```
JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
// Extract the value for the key called "title"
String title = volumeInfo.optString("title");
// Extract the array for the key called "authors"
JSONArray authors = volumeInfo.optJSONArray("authors");
```

Comment: which library you are using for JSON processing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSONArray to String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871309/convert-jsonarray-to-string-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function

```
String[] authors_arr(JSONArray authors){
    String[] authors_res=new String[authors.length()];
    try {
    for(int i=0;i<authors.length();i++)
    {
        authors_res[i]=authors.getString(i);
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return authors_res;
}
```

call it like this `String[] authors_string_array = authors_arr(authors);`
The main point is to loop through your json array and add it into your array

Answer (score 1):

```
private ArrayList<String> authorarray = new ArrayList<String>();    

for (int i = 0; i < authors.length(); i++) {
    String author = authors.getString(i);
    //add author to your array
    authorarray.add(author);
    }
```