# How do I fetch a JSON array from PHP to my java code?

Tags: java, php, android-studio, retrofit

My JSON response is like this:

```
["item1","item2",...]
```

Now, I want to add each of the array items into my `spinner`:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
    if (response.body() != null) {
       String[] arr=response.body().split(",");
       arr[0]=arr[0].replace("[","");
       arr[arr.length-1]=arr[arr.length-1].replace("]","");
       Arrays.sort(arr);
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr);                     
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       if (qrtr_reg != null) {
          qrtr_reg.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
    }
}
```

All my spinner items are in double quotes(""), which I don't want. I want them in object format. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** Tried the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = null;
try {
    array = new JSONArray(response.body());
    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){                   
       arr.add(String.valueOf(array.getJSONObject(i).getString(0)));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Collections.sort(arr);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
if (qrtr_reg != null) {
   qrtr_reg.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now, my spinner is completely empty!!

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/json.html) instead of trying to do the json conversion by yourself ?

Comment: Unlike the above article, the array I am fetching doesn't have any `key`:`value` pair. It's simply in this format `["item1","item2",...]`. It's an indexed array

Comment: Since you are using `e.printStackTrace()`, have you checked logcat to see if there is an error? Or better, can you put in proper error handling to show an error message when the JSON parsing fails?

Comment: Yes I get this error `Value item1 at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: Try just array.getString(i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second piece of code is *almost* correct. Here is the mistake:

```
arr.add(String.valueOf(array.getJSONObject(i).getString(0)))
```

Your array is not an array of JSON objects, it is an array of strings directly. Therefore, here is what that line should look like:

```
arr.add(array.getString(i))
```

(I'm guessing you copied your attempt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871355/829970), but the question there has an array of objects, and your array is much simpler.)